# .NET XslTransform mystery - META charset in transformation output

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

I have following piece of code:

```
        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xslt.Transform(document, xslArg, stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
```

That transformation outputs HTML document. What is bewildering to me is that even though the input xsl contains:

```
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    @page Section1
                    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
                    margin:42.55pt 42.55pt 42.55pt 70.9pt;
                    mso-header-margin:35.45pt;
                    mso-footer-margin:35.45pt;
                    mso-paper-source:0;}
                    div.Section1
                    {page:Section1;}
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="Section1">
                .....
```

output is :

```
<html xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>.....
```

as you see, charset info was added, apart from other stuff.

But what really amazed me, was that when I changed code that makes transformation into:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        xslt.Transform(document, xslArg, writer);
    }
    var result = sb.ToString();
    return result;
```

generated output had the following form:

```
<html xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">
    <style>....
```

As you can see, charset has changed. I guess it's because StringBuilder, and .NET by default operates using UTF-16. But, why transformation appends META tag with charset anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well either your stylesheet has `<xsl:output method="html"/>` or the root element of the result tree has the local name `html` and is in no namespace. In both cases the XSLT specification mandates that the XSLT processors adds a meta element with content type and charset in the head section when serializing the result tree.